# What kind of carpet should i use to replace the old one in my car?

Tags: car, old-cars

I own a 1996 Mitsubishi L300/Delica and the carpet is all worn out. Should i use a special type of carpet thats made for cars or i can simply use carpets for houses?

Comment: I believe "shopping" questions are off-topic here but...  There are two possibilities that come to mind.  There are companies that make aftermarket auto carpet replacements.  Some may have your make/model available.  There are also sources for bulk automotive carpet.  I'd use that rather than home carpet.

Comment: Probably opinion-based.  I know people who've used home carpet offcuts, even artificial grass offcuts.

Comment: @Chenmunka its not an opinion, like weather it looks good or not. Its about which works best in terms of durability, fitment, price ease of cleaning and many other factors.

Comment: There is no "best", Stelios. Those are opinion. My best will be entirely different to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the benefit of interpreting your question as "what are the advantages of molded vs universal automotive carpet?" If an exact fit replacement is available I would go that route. Of course the cost of the carpet must be relative to the value of the car. You don't want to spend three times what the car is worth for carpet. The advantage of an exact fit carpet is it will be molded to the contours of the interior. If you look at your floor you will see a lot of curves, bumps and angles. The molded carpet fits these shapes. A flat universal piece will have wrinkles and folds where you don't want them. I would avoid home interior carpet as it will tend to grow mold when it gets wet. Outdoor rated carpet may be better but still not the ideal choice.